# Coefficient of the features in the decision function. random forest

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

How can i do to get coefficient of the features in `RandomForest()` like **model.coef_** in logistic regression.?

```
model = GridSearchCV(estimator=classifier,  param_grid=grid_param,
                     scoring='roc_auc',
                     cv=5,
                     n_jobs=-1) 
best_model= model.fit(X_train, y_train)
best_model.feature_importances_
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Random forest` is an ensemble of `decision trees`, it is not a linear model. Sklearn provides importance of individual features which were used to train a random forest classifier or regressor. It can be accessed as follows, and returns an array of decimals which sum to 1.

```
model.feature_importances_
```

If you want to see this in combination of feature names, then you can use `zip(<feature names>, model.feature_importances_)`, and cast it to `list`.

Comment: What is meant by "doesn't work"? What did you try and what is the error you got?

Comment: AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'

Comment: `feature_importances_` is an attribute of `RandomForestClassifier`. Since you are using `GridSearchCV`, you can try `model.best_estimator_.feature_importances_`. Also, I am assuming that you have used `RandomForestClassifier` as your `estimator`.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear which framework you're using, or even if you are using a framework...

But, if you are using sklearn, then you can access the feature importance with `model.feature_importances_`.